# Can't loop in Python

Tags: python

I try to loop the code so it will ask the user if it wants to calculate again and if they don't the code will end. I'm sorry I'm new to coding.

Here's the code. Anyone know what to do?

```
print("Kalkulator Luas, Diameter dan Lilitan Bulatan\n") 

potato = int(input("Adakah anda mahu mencari 1. Luas 2. Diameter 3. Lilitan : "))

if potato > 3:
    print("You cant do that")
    exit()

apple = int(input("Sila masukkan jejari bulatan anda : "))

if potato == "1":
    print("Luas bulatan ialah : ", 3.141 * apple ** 2)
elif potato == "2":
    print("Diameter bulatan ialah : ", 2 * apple)
elif potato == "3":
    print("Lilitan bulatan ialah : ", 2 * 3.141 * apple)

while True:
    answer = input("Do you want another operation?")

if answer == "Yes":
    print("Good")
    continue
else:
    print("You cant do that")
    break
```

Comment: While loops only loop the contents within their indentation. The only thing you have indented is `answer = input ...` you need to indent your other lines as well

Answer (score 1):

### These changes can help the code work the way you want:

1. Take the whole program into a loop so that the user can use the calculator again;
2. Since potato is an Int type, you can remove the quotation marks;
3. For the code to work properly, you need to add indents at the end. For Python, they are important.
4. Improve the condition, because the program will accept a negative number and zero, although it should not.
5. Remove the `continue` in the last `if`, it is not needed there because the loop starts again anyway.
6. (Optional) It is also good practice to replace `answer == "Yes"` with `answer.lower() == "yes"`. In this case both "Yes" and "yes" and "YeS" will be treated as "yes" and the program will continue.

### So, the code looks like that:

```
print("Kalkulator Luas, Diameter dan Lilitan Bulatan\n") 

while True:
    potato = int(input("Adakah anda mahu mencari 1. Luas 2. Diameter 3. Lilitan : "))

    if potato < 1 or potato > 3:
        print("You cant do that")
        exit()

    apple = int(input("Sila masukkan jejari bulatan anda : "))

    if potato == 1:
        print("Luas bulatan ialah : ", 3.141 * apple ** 2)
    elif potato == 2:
        print("Diameter bulatan ialah : ", 2 * apple)
    elif potato == 3:
        print("Lilitan bulatan ialah : ", 2 * 3.141 * apple)

    answer = input("Do you want another operation?")

    if answer == "Yes":
        print("Good")
    else:
        print("You cant do that")
        break
```

### And this is what the code looks like with `.lower()`:

```
print("Kalkulator Luas, Diameter dan Lilitan Bulatan\n") 

while True:
    potato = int(input("Adakah anda mahu mencari 1. Luas 2. Diameter 3. Lilitan : "))

    if potato < 1 or potato > 3:
        print("You cant do that")
        exit()

    apple = int(input("Sila masukkan jejari bulatan anda : "))

    if potato == 1:
        print("Luas bulatan ialah : ", 3.141 * apple ** 2)
    elif potato == 2:
        print("Diameter bulatan ialah : ", 2 * apple)
    elif potato == 3:
        print("Lilitan bulatan ialah : ", 2 * 3.141 * apple)

    answer = input("Do you want another operation?")

    if answer.lower() == "yes":
        print("Good")
    else:
        print("You cant do that")
        break
```

I was careful not to use a lot of complex methods and not to change the code unnecessarily so that you understand this answer. If you know Python well enough, you can see the answer below with a more complex in some places, but elegant solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74004036/19830436

Comment: And you could even drop the `continue`. The loop continues anyway.

Comment: @Matthias, right, thx. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Python uses indentation to indicate a block of code. If you indent your while block, the loop will start working as you expect.

```
print("Kalkulator Luas, Diameter dan Lilitan Bulatan\n") 

potato = int(input("Adakah anda mahu mencari 1. Luas 2. Diameter 3. Lilitan : "))

if potato > 3:
    print("You cant do that")
    exit()

apple = int(input("Sila masukkan jejari bulatan anda : "))

if potato == "1":
    print("Luas bulatan ialah : ", 3.141 * apple ** 2)
elif potato == "2":
    print("Diameter bulatan ialah : ", 2 * apple)
elif potato == "3":
    print("Lilitan bulatan ialah : ", 2 * 3.141 * apple)

while True:
    answer = input("Do you want another operation?")

    if answer == "Yes":
        print("Good")
        continue
    else:
        print("You cant do that")
        break
```

you should use while loop on the  2nd line so it will ask all the requered questions from the user.

like this

```
print("Kalkulator Luas, Diameter dan Lilitan Bulatan\n") 

while True:
    potato = int(input("Adakah anda mahu mencari 1. Luas 2. Diameter 3. Lilitan : "))

    if potato > 3:
       print("You cant do that")
       exit()

    apple = int(input("Sila masukkan jejari bulatan anda : "))

    if potato == "1":
        print("Luas bulatan ialah : ", 3.141 * apple ** 2)
    elif potato == "2":
        print("Diameter bulatan ialah : ", 2 * apple)
    elif potato == "3":
        print("Lilitan bulatan ialah : ", 2 * 3.141 * apple)


    answer = input("Do you want another operation?")

    if answer == "Yes":
        print("Good")
        continue
    else:
        print("You cant do that")
        break
```

Comment: What do you think will happen if input is "Yes" in your *while* loop?

Answer (score 0):

You have many other issues in your code that should be addressed before adding to it. It currently will not function properly, and adding complexity will make debugging more difficult going forwards.

1. The `if` statements checking the value of `potato` will never match.

This is because `potato` is an integer (a number) and you are comparing it strings (text), which will never evaluate as true. To fix that you should change `"1"`, `"2"`, and `"3"` to `1`, `2`, and `3`.

2. Your input has no error handling.

If the user enter any non-numerical text, the program will bring up an error and crash, if trying to convert it to an integer. Even for the last comparison when you check to see if it's `"Yes"`, it will not match if the user doesn't properly capitalize their answer.

1. There are parts of your code that do nothing.

```py
if answer == "Yes":
    print("Good")
    continue
else:
    print("You cant do that")
    break
```

`continue` and `break` are only used in loops and are not relevant or needed in your current code. The if-else statement at the bottom should look like the if-else statements you wrote above:

```py
if answer == "Yes":
    print("Good")
else:
    print("You cant do that")
```

While it is exciting to learn new things, I feel like you would have a more enjoyable experience if you come to understand the fundamentals before moving on to more complex topics, as it will test and use the basics that you learned before.

Answer (score -1):

```
i = 0
while i != 1:
    print("Kalkulator Luas, Diameter dan Lilitan Bulatan\n") 
    potato = int(input("Adakah anda mahu mencari 1. Luas 2. Diameter 3. Lilitan : "))

    if potato > 3 or potato < 1:
        print("You cant do that")
        exit()
    apple = int(input("Sila masukkan jejari bulatan anda : "))

    if potato == 1:
        print("Luas bulatan ialah : ", 3.141 * apple ** 2)
    elif potato == 2:
        print("Diameter bulatan ialah : ", 2 * apple)
    elif potato == 3:
        print("Lilitan bulatan ialah : ", 2 * 3.141 * apple)

    answer = input("Do you want another operation?")
    if answer == "Yes":
        print("Good")
    else:
        print("You cant do that")
        i = 1
```

also, if you made the variable "potato" int, then the number in the comparison is written without quotes (in another version, it will be str).

Comment: What if potato == -1 ?

Comment: if potato > 3 or potato < 1:

Answer (score -1):

This is a good example of where match/case is more elegant. For example:

```
PI = 3.1416

print("Kalkulator Luas, Diameter dan Lilitan Bulatan\n")

while True:
    potato = int(input("Adakah anda mahu mencari 1. Luas 2. Diameter 3. Lilitan: "))
    if 1 <= potato <= 3:
        apple = float(input("Sila masukkan jejari bulatan anda: "))
        match potato:
            case 1:
                print("Luas bulatan ialah : ", PI * apple ** 2)
            case 2:
                print("Diameter bulatan ialah : ", 2 * apple)
            case 3:
                print("Lilitan bulatan ialah : ", 2 * PI * apple)
        if input('adakah anda mahu meneruskan? ') == 'Yes':
            print('baik')
        else:
            break
    else:
        print('Anda tidak boleh berbuat demikian')
```